# Problema con una propiedad que no existe

Tags: angular

Estoy haciendo una nota de venta la cual tiene una matriz de detalles, pero me sale este error:

> Property 'libro' does not exist on type 'Detalle[]'

Éste es el código:

```
class Nota de venta

  import { Cuenta } from "./cuenta";
  import { Detalle } from "./detalle";


   export class NotaVenta {
      constructor(){
          this.cuenta=new Cuenta();
      }

  idNotaventa!:number;
  cuenta!:Cuenta;
  fechaRegistro!:Date;
  valorTotal!:number;
  detalles!:Detalle[];
}

class detalle

 import { Libro } from "./libro";

  export class Detalle {
        constructor(){
           this.libro=new Libro();
         }

   idDetalle!:string;
   libro!:Libro;
   cantidad!:number;
   subtotal!:number;
}

class libro 

    export class Libro {
           constructor(){ }

   isbn!: string;
   titulo!:string;
   }
```

**HTML**

```
   <tr *ngFor="let p of librosSeleccionados;let i=index">
   <th  [(ngModel)]="nota.detalles.libro.isbn" name="isbn" ngDefaultControl>{{p.isbn}}</th>
  </tr>
```

Aquí es donde me sale error, ya que se me marca la parte de libro y me dice:

> Property 'libro' does not exist on type 'Detalle[]'.ngtsc(2339)

**component**

```
    constructor(private modal:NgbModal, private libroService:LibroService,private notaventaService:NotaventaService){}
nota:NotaVenta=new NotaVenta();
notas:NotaVenta[]=[];

ngOnInit(): void {
this.libroService.getAllL().subscribe((l=>{this.libros=l}));
}

create():void{
     this.notaventaService.create(this.nota).subscribe(
      res=>this.router.navigate(['/notas_de_venta']))
 }
```

Comment: Claro, porque no se trata de un Objeto de tipo Detalle, se trata de un Array de Detalle.

Comment: entonces, como le puedo solucionar?

Comment: La variable `nota` es una instancia de la clase `NotaVenta`, que a su vez cuenta con una propiedad `detalles` que es una matriz de instancias de `Detalle`. Eso significa que para poder acceder a la propiedad `libro` deberías indicar de cuál de los elementos de la matriz deseas obtener esa propiedad. Es decir, `nota.detalles[numero].libro.isbn`. donde `numero` sería el índice del elemento que deseas mostrar. El problema está en que sin ver el código en su conjunto no sabemos qué elemento quieres. PD: Te sugeriría sangrar adecuadamente el código para facilitar su lectura, análisis y comprensión.

Comment: `nota.detalles.map((obj:any)=>{
  return console.log(obj.isbn);
})` asi te daras cuenta de como acceder a la estructura de detalles

Comment: muchas gracias por responder, perdón, como soy muy nueva no se si me exprese bien, pero , yo quiero guardar estos valores, no mostrarlos, lo que sucede es que yo ya tengo un registro de libros previamente guardado, entonces simplemente quería guardar el isbn y la cantidad de libros vendidos(siendo este un nuevo valor) en la parte de nota de venta.

Answer (score 0):

Para poder acceder hay que recorrer a detalles :

```
   this.detalles = [{ isbn: 6897, titulo: 'que tal' }, { isbn: 6897, titulo: 'que tal' }]
    this.libros = this.detalles.map((obj: any) => {
      let nuevos = { isbn: obj.isbn, titulo: obj.titulo }
      return nuevos;
    })
    console.log(this.libros)
//html
<table>
  <th *ngFor="let libro of libros">{{libro.isbn}}</th>
</table>
```